# xgboost + pipenv = </3

Tags: python, anaconda, xgboost, pipenv

I love xgboost. And I love pipenv. But they don't love each other :(

`pipenv install xgboost`

> Error:  An error occurred while installing xgboost!
>   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9cab91je/xgboost/

I've installed a [compiled version of xgboost with anaconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/xgboost) but I just can't get it to play nicely with pipenv...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Whats your OS Windows?

Comment: I'm on macOS...

Comment: have you tried installing from the source? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xgboost/

Comment: Do you try `pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost.git#egg=release_0.81` ?

Comment: I ran into this issue after upgrading from python 3.6 to 3.7 on Windows. I (stupidly) downloaded 32bit python. So when I tried to install xgboost via pipenv I was getting the above error (or something similar). I was finally able to install xgboost via pipenv after downloading xgboost 0.82 cp37 cp37m win32.whl. That’s when the lightbulb went off. After installing 64bit Python, `pipenv install xgboost` worked just fine. Long story short, check your python version…

Answer (score 1):

on macos (10.13.6) i fixed this by installing cmake with brew. I had the same(-ish) error message, but the full error output included references to not finding the cmake command.

```
brew install cmake
```

my error message:

> 'ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.'

Comment: this worked for me also, in a `nvidia/cuda:10.2-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu18.04` docker image